# Seria possível passar uma string de uma form para outra?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Imaginem uma `Form` que vos pede uma cor, então teria uma `TextBox`, e a partir desse `TextBox` eu queria que ao Premir o botão **"OK"** por exemplo, isso envia-se o texto desse `TextBox` para outra `Form`, de maneira a que fosse possível aparecer em um `Label` desse `Form` com o texto quando a abrisse, como o poderia fazer ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow faça um [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e edite sua pergunta.

Comment: Primeiramente, você não precisa colocar a tag *visual-studio* porque o seu problema não tem **nenhuma** relação com a sua IDE. Segundo, você não precisa colocar a linguagem no título da pergunta, coloque-a como tag - é pra isso que elas servem. Terceiro, você já tentou alguma coisa? Poste o código que você já tem para podermos te ajudar melhor, se ainda não tentou nada explique melhor seu problema e coloque algum pseudo-código se achar que isso pode ajudar nosso entendimento. Por último, a resposta abaixo atende suas necessidades? Se não, eu farei uma resposta mais detalhada para você.

Comment: Você sempre pode melhorar suas perguntas/respostas clicando em [edit].

Comment: A propósito, [ele já fez o tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed?userid=36933) @MarconcilioSouza

Comment: @jbueno Já editei o título. Não sei que mais adicionar para vos ajudar, simplesmente peço um exemplo de uma maneira de passar uma string de uma forma para a outra como pergunta o título, e a resposta abaixo não atende ás minhas necessidades, não.

Comment: Bom, tem informação necessária faltando: o segundo form já estará aberto ou será aberto na hora que pressionar o botão?

Comment: Realmente, não prestei atenção a esse detalhe porque eu sabia fazer abrir uma nova forma ao pressionar o botão, mas já editei a pergunta, espero que já esteja melhor

Comment: @jbueno, quando tinha postado ele ainda não tinha feito.

Comment: Fazia quase uma hora que ele tinha feito :P Mas sem stress, foi só pra comentar mesmo

Comment: xD deiam - me um desconto, só tenho 14 anos vá lá..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviamente você tem dois forms, vamos chamar o form principal de `Form1` e o secundário de `Form2`

No `Form1` principal você terá um botão com evento de click semelhante ao abaixo

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //Aqui você vai pegar o valor do textBox
    string valor = textBoxCor.Text;

    //Aqui chamar o outro form passando o valor como parâmetro
    var form = new Form2(valor);
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Para isso funcionar, será necessário adicionar outro construtor (ou alterar o construtor existente) no segundo form.

```
public Form2(string cor){
    InitializeComponent();
    labelCor.Text = cor; //O label está recebendo o valor que foi recebido por parâmetro
}
```

Relacionado: [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73530/para-que-serve-um-construtor)