# Quando clicar no botão do form 2 atualizar label do form 1

Tags: c#, winforms

Como posso puxar a label do form1 para o form2 para dar label.Refresh?

Comment: Qual tipo de aplicação?

Comment: WinForms, esqueci de colocar

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102839/18246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você instanciar o form 2 ao construir ele (Abrir o form), você precisa passar uma referencia ao objeto do form 1 (Form Anterior), ou seja ter uma propriedade do tipo Form1. Para que no form 2 você chame um método publico que atualize, ou acesse diretamente a propriedade do objeto se ele for publico.
Estudar orientação a objeto ajuda a entender melhor.

Exemplo de como ficaria a classe dos dois Forms:
Form 1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public label labelNome;

    public void AbrirForm2()
    {
        Form2 segundoForm = new Form2();
        segundoForm.form1Reference = this;
    }
}
```

Form 2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form1 form1Reference = null;

    public void EventoQueAlteraLabelDoForm1()
    {
        if(form1Reference != null)
            form1Reference.labelNome.text = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, sou iniciante em c#

Comment: Tentei deixar mais fácil de entender. Você conseguiu ?

Comment: Eu queria editar uma label já existente no Form 1

Comment: Eu obtive este erro: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.'